# Laravel passport, Axios set token in bootstrap.js

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, axios

I made a **Laravel REST api**, what I called with **axios** (in vue app). I made the **laravel passport** auth in server side, so I have to insert *'Authorization : Bearer xxx...'* into the header of ajax calls.

I thought, I made my code as dry as possible, so in my bootstrap.js (where I init the axios) made this code:

```
function getTokens() {
    axios.get('/oauth/personal-access-tokens')
            .then(response => {
                  // window.usertokens = response.data;
                  if(response.data && response.data[0]&& response.data[0].id) {
                    var tokenid = response.data[0].id;
                    var auth = 'Bearer ' + tokenid;
                    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = auth;
                    window.authToken = auth;
                    if(window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']) {
                      console.debug("token has been set succesfully. (token=" + window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] + ")");
                    }
                  }
              //
            }).catch(e => {
              console.error("gettoken errror: " + e);
            });
};
```

On the console I wrote that the Authorization is set, BUT when I check the headers of ajax calls, there is no Authorization.

I know **the problem is based on the asynchronous call..** But is there **any solution, for do it nice**? (one time I ask the token and set).

Thx the suggestions and responses in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not use the default headers for this. You will get much tighter control by managing the bearer token yourself and supplying it in the config object for each call.

```
function getTokens() {
    axios.get('/oauth/personal-access-tokens')
            .then(response => {
                  // window.usertokens = response.data;
                  if(response.data && response.data[0]&& response.data[0].id) {
                    var tokenid = response.data[0].id;
                    var auth = 'Bearer ' + tokenid;
                    store.axiosConfig = { headers : { 'Authorization' : auth }}
                  }
              //
            }).catch(e => {
              console.error("gettoken errror: " + e);
            });
};
```

then to use it from some Vue component...

```
// this will run whenever you assign the config, and not before!
watch:{
    'store.axiosConfig' : function(){
        if(this.store.axiosConfig)
            axios.get('http://some-url',null,this.store.axiosConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thx the answer! its a good idea, but the code axios.get is run before the axiosconfig is set.. any idea, how can i wait untill it is set?

Comment: Well if you're doing the get from a Vue component, put it in a watch, that watches the store location? That would be a nice solution.

Comment: Answer updated. Another solution would be to put requests needing the token in a then() after getting the token?

Comment: Its a good idea, but I use the axios call in actions of store.. I found a solution, where I set a interceptors in axios, its not the best solution.. but I give it a chance